# Does painting over stylized wall tile in bathroom look good?

Tags: bathroom, painting

[image: sample of tile here]

We are preparing to list our house to sell and are nervous to paint over the tiles for fear it will look worse. There are spots that really need to be addressed, the image is of a spot that's in good condition.

Will painting over these types of tiles look ok?

Comment: I wouldn't do it. If it is just the grout that is discolored, the grout can be removed (sawed out) and replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Will they look OK?
Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.
If a buyer likes how it looks you are golden.

Here is a portion of an article from [Sherwin Williams on painting tile](https://www.sherwin-williams.com/property-facility-managers/education/styles-and-techniques/sw-article-pro-resuscitateold).

> Most ceramic tiles can be painted, as long as it's not frequently subjected to water or heavy wear. For instance, you can paint tiles on a bathroom wall, but avoid painting tiles that line a bathtub, shower, or that is on the floor or a countertop. Frequent exposure to moisture could cause the newly applied paint to blister and peel. Heavy abrasion from foot traffic or countertop use could cause the paint to wear prematurely.
>   Many experts have doubts about painting tile because the results can vary, depending on the type of tile, the products used to refinish them and the process followed.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you will be in this house for a very very long time and will always like painted tile.

Basically, it sounds like you want things to look nice.   That's great.

If the tile is considered a 3 out of 10 on looks why switch to painted tiles that will maybe make it 5 out of 10 at best.

There are paints that will adhere to tile.  HOWEVER when bumped the paint scrapes off versus on a wall it usually smushes in for the most part and you have an indention that is painted.

Now there are recoating services that will spray on paint/"fake"-epoxy glaze.   These look pretty good and the good companies have perfected these to perform well.  These are all one color and if you are OK with that, that is a great option.   Costly but this will look way more professional than a paint DIY.   (I am an advocate of almost everything DIY, this the consumer options simply look horrible and don't work)

The other gotcha I have is if there are indentions on the artwork on that tile, it may not look well reglazed/resurfaced.   I would vote heavily against anything if there are any indentions/raised parts of the tile.

Last thing.   Value your time and money.   Painting it will cost time and money.  If retiling it costs a little more time and money then do that.   If you are going to eventually retile - do it first.   Retiling isn't hard since if the tile is laying flat now it is on a good tiling substrate.  It isn't hard removing this tile and putting up new stuff.